# This copy of Microsoft Office is not genuine

Tags: windows, microsoft-office

I have a legitimate, already-activated copy of Microsoft Office 2007 Enterprise.

Both my best friend and his dad have the same copy installed on their machines as well, but they don't get this error message, only me:

[image]

I start getting it whenever I open a new document. I've clicked on the "Learn More" button, but it doesn't provide any other options than buying Microsoft Office.

Any ideas?

Comment: You didn't read the contract? A common Microsoft Office license cannot be used on more than one computer. Your "legit" copy of MS Office is now stained. Sorry.

Comment: Note, that the "Genuine Advantage" is not an advantage for your user experience *at all*. It is a tool which enables them to nag you when you *appear* to be abusing their (perfectly valid) license terms.  (I'm not commenting on your use or misuse of the license, just the "Genuine Advantage" tool itself.)

Answer (score 12):

I doubt anybody here at Super User has access to a Microsoft Product Activation server.

Please contact Microsoft (they are the guys with the finger on the killswitch after all :) and explain the situation to a representative. This happens quite frequently, and they're usually very helpful (IF the other installations are no longer in use; if they are, then the rule 'one installation per license' applies and you can't use it legally).

Answer (score 4):

I have to agree with everyone else here - based on the information you have provided, your copy is **not** genuine.

In Microsoft genuine advantage-land, the spoils go to the one who validates first. It's not clear from your post who purchased the software, but if it was you & then you gave it to you best friend to install & they validated successfully, then as far as Microsoft is concerned, it's not yours any more.

If you can get your friend to uninstall it, call Microsoft as Molly explained.

Answer (score 3):

Some [EULAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-user_license_agreement) state that a user may install the software on a desktop AND a portable machine (notebook) that is to be exclusively used by the same one user. The reason the two prior activations (dad and friend) work is because it used up the two activations per license.

**It's still breach of license to install it on two machines for two or more people** -- but this is the technical reason why the two prior activations are probably still working.

Adobe CS4 Design Premium Suite is like this and it's likely Office is too-- copy-and-paste from Office 2007 EULA:

> a. Licensed Device. You may install and use one copy of the
>   software on the licensed device. 
>   b. Portable Device. You may install another copy on a portable
>   device for use by the single primary
>   user of the licensed device.

Bottom line: YOU may install it on one desktop, and one notebook just for you.

Comment: Possibly, but IMHO it's more likely they don't have WGA installed.

Comment: Ah yea, hadn't considered that.  I haven't tried a setup without WGA installed -- but -- If WGA isn't installed, what generated the error?  I didn't think OFfice on its' own can to validation like that.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a volume license, you need one copy per PC. Your dad and friend will need to get their own copy.